# Outlook clients unable to connect to Exchange and OWA timeouts

Tags: windows-server-2003, exchange-2007, exchange-2003, outlook

I have an exchange 2007 mailbox server and two client access servers. There was an original exchange 2007 mailbox server/client access server that died and is still listed in the organization.  As of late users are intermittently not able to connect with Outlook2003/2007.  If they launch the program a couple of times they will be able to connect.

OWA is only accessed on one of the client access servers and it is giving users intermittent error

Exception
Exception type: System.Web.HttpException
Exception message: Request timed out.

Exchange 2003 is still installed on the original Exchange 2003 server which is a DC (I know).

I know that the old servers need to be properly decommissioned but I am curious why this has become an issue only recently.  Do you think just doing the proper decommission will fix the problems or does seem like these need to be resolved before any proper troubleshooting can take place?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There was an original exchange 2007 mailbox server/client access server that died and is still listed in the organization.

I suspect this is your problem right now. Your symptoms are consistent with a failing auto-discover process. If 'autodiscover.yourdomain' still lists the dead server in its list, it would quite easily explain why your Outlook 2003/2007 client sometimes can't connect.